# Восстановление GRUB после удаления тома в Windows

Tags: linux, windows, файловая-система, grub, boot

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему от своих кривых рук(

Установлены две ОС Windows 10, CentOS 7. GRUB был по умолчанию настроен так, что предлагает выбор из CentOS и Windows Boot. В определенный момент под виндой стал доступен(виден) том размером 1gb, который имел файловую систему RAW, висел новым томом (E:) и соответственно никак не открывался. Я удалил том через стандартную утилиту винды для разметки дисков. В результате grub запускается(при выборе CentOS7) и выдает, что

```
error: no such device: 8248d7ec-6d53-4c3d-bbb8-dea891f61703.
error: disk `hd0,gpt6` not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Винда стартует без проблем. Т.е подозрение, что я поломал бут секцию линукса.

После этого вернулся в винду и вернул том, с RAW файловой системой, что конечно ни к чему не привело, а возможно сделало хуже. Понимаю, что каким-то образом нужно восстановить grub? Есть live-usb с Debian. Любых упоминаний форматирования я избегал и предполагаю его не было.

Попытка сделать mount через live cd приводит к тому, что "unknown filesystem", проверки fsck и ntfsfix ничего не дали. В списке устройств предположительная область диска значится как Microsoft'овская

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы удалили /boot. Восстановление grub ничего не даст, так как в этом разделе находится ядро linux.

Можно попытаться восстановить данные testdisk'ом или другой специализированной программой, а после тогда уже перезаписывать grub. Проще будет переустановить систему.

Comment: Да, я затер разметку для секции с /boot. Пытался восстановить с помощью testdisk'a, но наломал дров. Переустановить систему оказалось проще